# Storing 3D models in Android SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I would like to know if it is possible to store 3D objects into android SQLite Database to retrieve the object and use it. If it is possible, then may I know if there are any tutorials/ guidelines to do it? Else any other way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: You can store pretty much anything in a [`BLOB`](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) column, but that doesn't automatically mean it's a good idea. I suppose what's missing in your question is the *why* you're considering to store 3D models in a database, as opposed to a straightforward alternative; i.e. storing the models as separate files on disk?

Comment: I am considering to store 3D models into a database because I am not sure if there are any alternatives which is better to do it and that is the only think I can think of as I still a beginner in android development. So storing models as separate file on disk? May I know how to do that and retrieve the object later on to display it on my application? Could you please guide me ? Thank you very much =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, it would be best to store models as collection of numbers in a proper database structures. I didn't specify what models you mean but if they can be described by a series of numbers (as most models do), you should be able to store them this way.

A very simple example is a rectangle. A rectangle may be described by 4 parameters: (x,y) of top-left corner and (x,y) of the bottom-right corner. So your database would have 4 columns to store those values for each rectangle. Obviously, 3D models are more complicated but can be expressed using a series of numbers too.

Comment: I am trying to store OpenGL ES 3D models. So may I know if I should just store the codes such as the vertex, coordinates into the database or should I store the whole object into the database?

Comment: I would store just what you call codes, i.e. the numeric representation that would allow you to restore the models.

Comment: Umm, sorry for asking a noob question, because I am still a beginner. Meaning to store the whole bunch of codes which created the 3D model in GLSurfaceView Renderer such as the variables and methods into the database?

Comment: May I know what it mean by a series of numbers as stated above?

Comment: In other words, the values of variables you use in your model.

Comment: Meaning whole thing like eg) 

 static float triangleCoords[] = { // in counterclockwise order:
         0.0f,  0.622008459f, 0.0f,   // top
        -0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
         0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f    // bottom right
    }; ?

Comment: Yes, all those numbers